# How to send link to the socket object?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a two buttons on a form. One is for creating object of `socket` class and start listening endpoint, and second is for stop listening it. I wrote a code for the first, but don't know how to send a link for the object of socket to the second, to close it. 
My code for the first button:

```
public void Listen()
{
 IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBoxIPListen.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPortListen.Text));
 UdpClient receiver = new UdpClient(point);
   try
   {
      while (true)
      {
        byte[] data = receiver.Receive(ref point);
        string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
        RecieveMessage(message);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

I tried to set it by the tag of the button, but it doesn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop is blocking your mainthread. You should create a thread for listening or use the async methods.

Look here for an example:

[UdpClient.BeginReceive Method (AsyncCallback, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive(v=vs.110).aspx)

And `How to send link to the socket object?`. You should create a field to store the UdpClient.

```
public class Form1
{
     private UdpClient _receiver;

     public void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         // create the socket etc,
         _receiver = new UdpClient(point);
     }

     public void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         // stop the socket.
         _receiver.Dispose();
     }
}
```